# Inference using GLM: can we do better than asymptotics?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, inference, asymptotics

Might be a beginner question, but if we have a generalized linear model and we want to do inference. Many textbooks (including MASS) talks about deviance and asymptotic distribution of deviance.

But a natural question is that, since we never have sample size of infinity, how reliable are those asymptotics result? Even the MASS textbook mentions that

> The approximation will often not improve as the sample size $n$ increases since the number of parameters under $S$ also increases and the usual likelihood ratio approximation argument does not apply.

So my question is, is there any altenatives than to using asymptotic approximation?

Comment: That quote applies specifically to using the deviance to assess goodness of fit relative to a saturated model. It does not apply, for example, to using analysis of deviance to test nested models, provided that the number of parameters in the two models do not grow with the sample size.

Comment: You have three quite distinct questions here. Are primarily interested in hypothesis tests?

Comment: Alternatives: 1) bootstrap (OK, also asymp) 2) bayes 3) higher order asymptotic approximations ...